# How can I add meeting url to .ics file

Tags: icalendar

Here is how I tried... I used URL property but in calendar(Microsoft Calendar) it is not reflected

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID://Elara/lofy/tanare/delp/314sum2015//
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20201028T170000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Kolkata:20201028T173000
SUMMARY:ION-Test
DESCRIPTION:Meeting to provide technical review for "Phoenix"   design.\nHappy Face Conference Room. Phoenix design team
URL:https://www.webex.com/
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 3):

The specification describes the URL property in general terms.   https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.6

I suggest check the various meeting scheduling tools and go with that.  Arguably the meeting URL is the 'location'.    For example ZOOM uses the LOCATION property. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.7   EG

```
LOCATION:https://us04web.zoom.us/j/72974416824?pwd=N2ZNVzJxejR6a1p3TWFSU1U1
 eUZwQT09
```

But then ZOOM also puts html in the DESCRIPTION which is not supported by all applications and not addressed by the specification.

Answer (score 1):

The URL property is not an arbitrary URL. It's the URL of the event itself. From the spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.6

> This property may be used in a calendar component to convey a location where a more dynamic rendition of the calendar information associated with the calendar component can be found.

If you want to associate a URL with the event, you'll have to put it in the description or location or in an X-property.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the the DESCRIPTION section is intended to be plain text, so it is not intended to have html url hyperlink. (See the RFC5545 specification)

Comment: hi @KenLee Thanks for the reply. What does this URL property do? it is not displayed in calendar event anywhere.